# Java - get JSON from XML and XPath

Tags: java, xml, json, xpath, xml-parsing

Is there an API which gives me JSON in String format if I pass my XML document and the XPath? If I pass the xpath and the XML document as below

```
/domain:networkConfig/devices[@type='computer']/device/ipDetails/ipDetail
```

XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<domain:networkConfig >
    <devices type="computer">
        <device vs:registerSysid="897">
            <ipDetails>
                <ipDetail nic="eth0" nicDesc="myZone" primaryEditable="false">
                    <ipAddress>192.168.31.101</ipAddress>
                    <gateway>192.168.31.31</gateway>
                    <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
                </ipDetail>
            </ipDetails>
            <routeDetails/>
        </device>
    </devices>
</domain:networkConfig>
```

Then it should give me the JSON as a String as

```
"ipDetail": {
    "nic": "eth0",
    "nicDesc": "myZone",
    "primaryEditable": false
}
```

Comment: what did you try so far ? May be your question should go here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

xslt 3.0 offers an xml-to-json() function, which is available in Saxon 9.6. You have to transform your XML to the right format before converting it to JSON, but transforming XML in XSLT is what the language is good at...